# Finding inverse of functions[methods of]

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse, function-and-relation-composition

I am now trying to understand functions, inverses and composites. I must admit am not getting a thing. But following some leads, I managed to work one as below. Is this a good understanding on hows and whys?

### Find the inverse of function $ y=\sqrt{6+x}$

$ y=\sqrt{6+x}$  can be expanded as $y^2=6+x$

solving for $x$ we get  $x=y^2-6$

swapping the position of $x$ and $y$ we get $y=x^2-6$

$ \therefore$ the inverse of $y=\sqrt{6+x}$    is  $$y=x^2-6$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Careful here, your work is actually correct (the swapping method is in fact standard), except that you must keep track of your domain. The inverse of $y=\sqrt{6+x}$ is $y=x^2-6$, and your work is absolutely correct. However the domain on $\sqrt{6+x}$ is $x \geq -6$, hence on the inverse, we have that $y \geq -6$.

Now for the inverse $y=x^2-6$, since $y \geq -6$, it follows that $x \geq 0$ as, 
$$x^2 -6 \geq -6 \Rightarrow x^2 \geq 0 \Rightarrow x \geq 0.$$ Now if you plot the two solutions you will have something that looks like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+Sqrt%5B6%2Bx%5D).

If you do not keep track of your domains and ranges like this, then your work is wrong as the inverse must be 1-1, and the inverse of the inverse must also be 1-1. The inverse of the inverse must give the function you started with on the correct domain.

Comment: @Sylvester You are quite welcome.

Answer (score 3):

That's almost it:

\begin{align}
y&=\sqrt{6+x}\\
y^2&=6+x\\
x&=y^2-6
\end{align}

And that's your answer. You don't "swap" x and y positions, you just solve for x or solve for y.

---

Many inverses are rather simple... Take for example:

$$y=x\iff x=y$$

When you have more complicated things like $$y=x^2$$ then you have $$x=\sqrt{y}$$

More complicated functions have defined inverses like $$y=10^x\iff x=\log_{10} y$$

and

$$y=e^x\iff x=\ln y$$

Then there are the trig functions:

$$y=\sin x\iff x=\arcsin y$$
$$y=\cos x\iff x=\arccos y$$
$$y=\tan x\iff x=\arctan y$$

At an elementary level, this is pretty much all you need to know.

Comment: so you imply my workings look pretty correct and follows the correct method? Given that I picked this method from some site, I'd thought it belongs to some cook book.

Comment: You were correct up until you decided to swap $x$ for $y$. You just need to solve for $x$ or $y$ and then you're done.

Comment: I don't know what level you're at, but be wary that the inverse of a function is not always a function due to the limitations in the definition of a function. It may not pass the "vertical line test" when drawn. Therefore, many inverse functions are only defined over specific intervals.

Comment: am still at precalculus level. Just started on this topic. I am trying to get myself going, meticulously but correctly. But am not understanding your comment about " not swapping"

Comment: I thought the swapping method is a "standard" because I used it to solve for $y^2=6=x$ and getting my solution as $ y=x^2-6$ and solving for $x$ and swapping.